# Is there a destructor for Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, destructor, finalize

Is there a destructor for Java? I don't seem to be able to find any documentation on this. If there isn't, how can I achieve the same effect?

To make my question more specific, I am writing an application that deals with data and the specification say that there should be a 'reset' button that brings the application back to its original just launched state. However, all data have to be 'live' unless the application is closed or reset button is pressed.

Being usually a C/C++ programmer, I thought this would be trivial to implement. (And hence I planned to implement it last.) I structured my program such that all the 'reset-able' objects would be in the same class so that I can just destroy all 'live' objects when a reset button is pressed.

I was thinking if all I did was just to dereference the data and wait for the garbage collector to collect them, wouldn't there be a memory leak if my user repeatedly entered data and pressed the reset button? I was also thinking since Java is quite mature as a language, there should be a way to prevent this from happening or gracefully tackle this.

Comment: There is only a memory leak if you hold references to objects you don't need. i.e. There is a bug in your program. The GC will run as it needs (sometimes sooner)

Comment: The virtual machine will not run GC soon enough if you are rapidly processing data through objects.  The idea that the GC can always keep up, or make the right decisions is a fallacy.

Comment: @Kieveli Wouldn't JVM run GC before giving an error?

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if there was destructor for Java that would destroy it once for all.

Comment: There is no exactly destructor class in Java, class destroyed in java automatically by garbage collector . but you could do that using below one but it's not exact same thing : **finalize()** There was [a question that spawned in-depth discussion of finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize) , so that you should get more depth if required...

Comment: @WVrock - Interesting question.  The answer is "no" (at least for some types of "rapidly processing data through objects") but for a nuanced reason.  The actual error you get occurs when you are spending something like 97% of the time in garbage collection and only 3% on actual program logic because most of the references still have pointers leading into them.  If the "rapid processing" uses a small number of pointers there won't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, there is one. It is called Oracle.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

Because Java is a garbage collected language you cannot predict when (or even if) an object will be destroyed. Hence there is no direct equivalent of a destructor.

There is an inherited method called `finalize`, but this is called entirely at the discretion of the garbage collector. So for classes that need to explicitly tidy up, the convention is to define a *close* method and use finalize only for sanity checking (i.e. if *close* has not been called do it now and log an error).

There was [a question that spawned in-depth discussion of finalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize) recently, so that should provide more depth if required...

Comment: Does "close()" in this context refer to the method in java.lang.Autocloseable?

Comment: No, AutoCloseable was introduced in Java 7 but the 'close()' convention has been around much longer.

Comment: why you cannot predict when (or even if) an object will be destroyed. what approximate other way to predict that ?

Comment: @dctremblay object destruction is done by garbage collector and garbage collector may never run in lifetime of application.

Comment: Note that the `finalize` method [has been deprecated](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html#JDK-8165641) in Java 9.

Comment: We can also use WeakReference - objects stored there will be deleted before garbage collector begins to search for garbage.

Comment: @dctremblay destruction of objects is not a thing. At some point of time, the memory of an unused object may get overwritten when it’s being used for another object. All work associated with garbage collection will be postponed until the memory is actually needed for another object. This might be never, if a) there are no subsequent allocations or b) there’s enough memory for all subsequent allocations. Even when the garbage collector runs, it normally doesn’t touch the garbage. Its main task is to ensure that still-in-use objects do not get overwritten. It doesn’t identify the dead objects.

Answer (score 146):

Have a look at the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. For example:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
  System.out.println(br.readLine());
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
} finally {
  ...
}
```

Here the resource that is no longer needed is freed in the `BufferedReader.close()` method. You can create your own class that implements `AutoCloseable` and use it in a similar fashion.

This statement is more limited than `finalize` in terms of code structuring, but at the same time it makes the code simpler to understand and maintain. Also, there is no guarantee that a `finalize` method is called at all during the livetime of the application.

Comment: I'm surprised this has so few votes. It is the actual answer.

Comment: Depends on Java 7 though, and there's still plenty of systems on Java 6 (and several hundred million Android devices, none of which have official support for Java 7.) As an end user, I want to have the latest Java version for security reasons, but as a developer, I don't want to shove things down my users throats. That's someone else's job. Still, +1, reminds me a lot of Python's `with`, which I do like.

Comment: I disagree that it is the actual answer. If an instance has a resource it handles over a larger period of time, across multiple method calls, then try-with-resources won't help. Unless it's ok to close and reopen said resource at the rate said methods get called at - not a general fact.

Comment: Indeed, this is _not_ the actual answer. It is impossible to use this structure to manage the destruction of an object unless the object's construction and use is entirely encapsulated by the `try` and the `finally` is used to force a call to `obj.finalize()`. And even this setup does not solve the problem posed by OP: object destruction mid-program triggered by a "reset" button.

Comment: Other users have shown this being done in your application entry point. Define your variable globally. Initialize it in the entry function, with try. Deinitialize on the finally (when your application closes). It is entirely possible.

Comment: @nurettin Java 7 had only been out for 3 months when the question was asked, if that helps make more sense of it.

Comment: @corsiKa it does, thanks. Also, this answer doesn't have few votes anymore.

Answer (score 115):

Nope, no destructors here. The reason is that all Java objects are heap allocated and garbage collected. Without explicit deallocation (i.e. C++'s delete operator) there is no sensible way to implement real destructors.

Java does support finalizers, but they are meant to be used only as a safeguard for objects holding a handle to native resources like sockets, file handles, window handles, etc. When the garbage collector collects an object without a finalizer it simply marks the memory region as free and that's it. When the object has a finalizer, it's first copied into a temporary location (remember, we're garbage collecting here), then it's enqueued into a waiting-to-be-finalized queue and then a Finalizer thread polls the queue with very low priority and runs the finalizer.

When the application exits, the JVM stops without waiting for the pending objects to be finalized, so there practically no guarantees that your finalizers will ever run.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning native resources - this is one area where a "destructor-like" method is useful.

Comment: yes, I am facing that same problem right now with freeing up resources / handles allocated via native calls to C++.

Comment: @ddimitrov, in theory could java implement explicit deallocation? Or is this a logical contradiction?

Comment: @mils naively implementing explicit deallocation would either break the Java assumption that any reference points to a live object. You may iterate over all pointers and null-out the aliases, but that is more expensive than GC. Or you can try to use some linear type system (see "ownership" in Rust), but that is a major language change. There are other options too (see JavaRT scoped memory, etc), but in general explicit deallocation doesn't fit well with the Java language.

Answer (score 32):

Use of *finalize()* methods should be avoided. They are not a reliable mechanism for resource clean up and it is possible to cause problems in the garbage collector by abusing them.

If you require a deallocation call in your object, say to release resources, use an explicit method call. This convention can be seen in existing APIs (e.g. [Closeable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), [Graphics.dispose()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose()), [Widget.dispose()](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html#dispose())) and is usually called via try/finally.

```
Resource r = new Resource();
try {
    //work
} finally {
    r.dispose();
}
```

Attempts to use a disposed object should throw a runtime exception (see [IllegalStateException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)).

---

EDIT:

> I was thinking, if all I did was just
>   to dereference the data and wait for
>   the garbage collector to collect them,
>   wouldn't there be a memory leak if my
>   user repeatedly entered data and
>   pressed the reset button?

Generally, all you need to do is dereference the objects - at least, this is the way it is supposed to work. If you are worried about garbage collection, check out [Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html) (or the equivalent document for your JVM version).

Comment: That's not what dereference means. It's not "set the last reference of an object to null" but rather getting (reading) the value from a reference so you can use it for subsequent operations.

Comment: Is try..finally still a valid and recommended approach? Suppose, I was previously calling a native method in finalize(), can I move the call to the finally clause?

```class Resource {
    finalize() {    destroy();    }

    protected native void destroy();
}

class Alt_Resource {
    try (Resource r = new Resource()) {
        // use r
    }
    finalize {
        r.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: r would not be scoped to the finally block. Therefore, you can't call destroy at that point. Now, if you correct the scope to have the object creation prior to the try block, you would end up with the ugly "before try-with-resources" case.

Answer (score 25):

With Java 1.7 released, you now have the additional option of using the `try-with-resources` block.  For example,

```
public class Closeable implements AutoCloseable {
    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("closing..."); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Closeable c = new Closeable()) {
            System.out.println("trying..."); 
            throw new Exception("throwing..."); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catching..."); 
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("finalizing..."); 
        } 
    }
}
```

If you execute this class, `c.close()` will be executed when the `try` block is left, and before the `catch` and `finally` blocks are executed.  Unlike in the case of the `finalize()` method, `close()` is guaranteed to be executed.  However, there is no need of executing it explicitly in the `finally` clause.

Comment: what if we didn't used try-with-resources block? I think we can call close in finalize() just to ensure that close has been called.

Comment: @shintoZ as I read in above answers there is no guarantee of `finalize()` execution

Answer (score 15):

I fully agree to other answers, saying not to rely on the execution of finalize.

In addition to try-catch-finally blocks, you may use [Runtime#addShutdownHook](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) (introduced in Java 1.3) to perform final cleanups in your program.

**That isn't the same as destructors are**, but one may implement a shutdown hook having listener objects registered on which cleanup methods (close persistent database connections, remove file locks, and so on) can be invoked - things that **would normally be done in destructors**.
Again - this is not a replacement for destructors but in some cases, you can approach the wanted functionality with this.

The advantage of this is having deconstruction behavior **loosely coupled** from the rest of your program.

Comment: addShutdownHook was apparently introduced in Java 1.3.  Anyway, it's available to me in 1.5. :)  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727151/how-do-i-cleanup-an-opened-process-in-java

Comment: FYI, in my experience shutdown hooks will not be called if you use the red "terminate" button in Eclipse - the entire JVM is destroyed immediately, shutdown hooks are not gracefully called. Meaning you may see different behavior during development and production if you develop using eclipse

Answer (score 13):

No, [`java.lang.Object#finalize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) is the closest you can get.

However, when (and if) it is called, is not guaranteed.
See: [`java.lang.Runtime#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean))

Comment: A method that may or may not get called is essentially useless in my book. It would have been better not to pollute the language with a useless special method that at best gives a false sense of security. I'll never understand why the developers of the Java language thought finalize was a good idea.

Comment: @antred [The developers of the Java language agree](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()). I guess, back then, for some of them, it was the first time they designed a programming language and runtime environment with garbage collection. What’s less understandable, is why that other managed language [copied that concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.finalize?view=netframework-4.8) at a time, when it was already understood that this concept is a bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with most of the answers.

You should not depend fully on either `finalize` or `ShutdownHook`

[finalize](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/finalize-method-in-java-tutorial.html)

1. The JVM does not guarantee when this `finalize()` method will be invoked.
2. `finalize()` gets called only once by GC thread. If an object revives itself from finalizing method, then `finalize` will not be called again.
3. In your application, you may have some live objects, on which garbage collection is never invoked.
4. Any `Exception` that is thrown by the finalizing method is ignored by the GC thread
5. `System.runFinalization(true)` and `Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization(true)` methods increase the probability of invoking `finalize()` method but now these two methods have been deprecated. These methods are very dangerous due to lack of thread safety and possible deadlock creation.

[shutdownHooks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread)

```
public void addShutdownHook(Thread hook)
```

> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.

The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:

1. The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, `System.exit`) method is invoked, or
2. The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.
3. A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but non-started thread. When the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run concurrently. When all the hooks have finished it will then run all uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled.
4. Finally, the virtual machine will halt. Note that daemon threads will continue to run during the shutdown sequence, as will non-daemon threads if the shutdown was initiated by invoking the exit method.
5. Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly. When a program invokes exit the expectation is that the virtual machine will promptly shut down and exit.

   But even Oracle documentation quoted that

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly

This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the `SIGKILL` signal on Unix or the `TerminateProcess` call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.

***Conclusion*** : ***use `try{} catch{} finally{}` blocks appropriately and release critical resources in  `finally(}` block. During release of resources in `finally{}` block, catch `Exception` and `Throwable`.***

Answer (score 8):

First, note that since Java is garbage-collected, it is rare to need to do anything about object destruction. Firstly because you don't usually have any managed resources to free, and secondly because you can't predict when or if it will happen, so it's inappropriate for things that you need to occur "as soon as nobody is using my object any more".

You can be notified after an object has been destroyed using java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (actually, saying it has been destroyed may be slightly inaccurate, but if a phantom reference to it is queued then it's no longer recoverable, which usually amounts to the same thing). A common use is:

- Separate out the resource(s) in your class that need to be destructed into another helper object (note that if all you're doing is closing a connection, which is a common case, you don't need to write a new class: the connection to be closed would be the "helper object" in that case).
- When you create your main object, create also a PhantomReference to it. Either have this refer to the new helper object, or set up a map from PhantomReference objects to their corresponding helper objects.
- After the main object is collected, the PhantomReference is queued (or rather it may be queued - like finalizers there is no guarantee it ever will be, for example if the VM exits then it won't wait). Make sure you're processing its queue (either in a special thread or from time to time). Because of the hard reference to the helper object, the helper object has not yet been collected. So do whatever cleanup you like on the helper object, then discard the PhantomReference and the helper will eventually be collected too.

There is also finalize(), which looks like a destructor but doesn't behave like one. It's usually not a good option.

Comment: Why a PhantomReference instead of a WeakReference?

Comment: @uckelman: if all you want is notification, then PhantomReference does the job, this is pretty much what it is designed for. The additional semantics of WeakReference aren't needed here, and at the point where your ReferenceQueue is notified, you can no longer recover the object through the WeakReference, so the only reason to use it is to save having to remember that PhantomReference exists. Any extra work that WeakReference does is probably negligible, but why bother with it?

Comment: Thank you for hinting at PhantomReference. It's not perfect, but still Better Than Nothing.

Comment: @SteveJessop what “extra work”, do you think, has a weak reference compared to a phantom reference?

Answer (score 6):

The `finalize()` function is the destructor.

However, it should not be normally used because it is invoked **after the GC** and you can't tell when that will happen (if ever).

Moreover, it takes more than one GC to deallocate objects that have `finalize()`.

You should try to clean up in the logical places in your code using the `try{...} finally{...}` statements!

Answer (score 4):

If it's just memory you are worried about, don't. Just trust the GC it does a decent job. I actually saw something about it being so efficient that it could be better for performance to create heaps of tiny objects than to utilize large arrays in some instances.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use a try ... finally block to finalize the object in the control flow at which you are using the object. Of course it doesn't happen automatically, but neither does destruction in C++. You often see closing of resources in the finally block.

Comment: This is the right answer when the resource in question has a single owner and never has references to it "stolen" by other code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [@Cleanup](https://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) annotation in Lombok that mostly resembles C++ destructors:

```
@Cleanup
ResourceClass resource = new ResourceClass();
```

When processing it (at compilation time), Lombok inserts appropriate `try-finally` block so that `resource.close()` is invoked, when execution leaves the scope of the variable. You can also specify explicitly another method for releasing the resource, e.g. `resource.dispose()`:

```
@Cleanup("dispose")
ResourceClass resource = new ResourceClass();
```

Comment: The advantage I see is that there will be less nesting (Which may be significant if you have a lot of objects that require "destroying").

Comment: A try-with-resource block can have multiple resources in one shot

Comment: But it cannot have instructions between them.

Comment: Fair. I suppose then the recommendation is to prefer try-with-resource, even for multiple resources, unless there needed to be instruction between them that forced you to make new try-with-resource blocks (increasing nesting), then use `@Cleanup`

Answer (score 2):

The closest equivalent to a destructor in Java is the [finalize()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) method.  The big difference to a traditional destructor is that you can't be sure when it'll be called, since that's the responsibility of the garbage collector.  I'd strongly recommend carefully reading up on this before using it, since your typical RAIA patterns for file handles and so on won't work reliably with finalize().

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking about the original question... which, I think we can conclude from all the other learned answers, and also from Bloch's essential [Effective Java](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Java-Second-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1482344538&sr=8-1&keywords=effective%20java), item 7, "Avoid finalizers", seeks the solution to a legitimate question in a manner which is inappropriate to the Java language...:

... wouldn't a pretty obvious solution to do what the OP actually wants be to keep all your objects which need to be reset in a sort of "playpen", to which all other non-resettable objects have references only through some sort of accessor object...

And then when you need to "reset" you disconnect the existing playpen and make a new one: all the web of objects in the playpen is cast adrift, never to return, and one day to be collected by the GC.

If any of these objects are `Closeable` (or not, but have a `close` method) you could put them in a `Bag` in the playpen as they are created (and possibly opened), and the last act of the accessor before cutting off the playpen would be to go through all the `Closeables` closing them... ?

The code would probably look something like this:

```
accessor.getPlaypen().closeCloseables();
accessor.setPlaypen( new Playpen() );
```

`closeCloseables` would probably be a blocking method, probably involving a latch (e.g. `CountdownLatch`), to deal with (and wait as appropriate for) any `Runnables`/`Callables` in any threads specific to the `Playpen` to be ended as appropriate, in particular in the JavaFX thread.

Answer (score 2):

Many great answers here, but there is some additional information about why you should avoid using [finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()).

If the JVM exits due to `System.exit()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exit()`, finalizers will not be run by default. From [Javadoc for Runtime.exit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)):

> *The virtual machine's shutdown sequence consists of two phases. In the first phase all registered shutdown hooks, if any, are started in some unspecified order and allowed to run concurrently until they finish. In the second phase all uninvoked finalizers are run if finalization-on-exit has been enabled. Once this is done the virtual machine halts.*

You can call [`System.runFinalization()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalization()) but it only makes "a best effort to complete all outstanding finalizations" – not a guarantee.

There is a [`System.runFinalizersOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean)) method, but don't use it – it's unsafe, deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you got the chance of using a **Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI)** framework such as [Weld](https://weld.cdi-spec.org/) you can use the Java annotation *@Predestroy* for doing cleanup jobs etc.

```
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
public class Foo {

  @javax.annotation.PreDestroy
  public void cleanup() {
    // do your cleanup    
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if it's not this one, a global object manager would have solved OP's original problem (a "reset button").

Answer (score 0):

Though there have been considerable advancements in Java's GC technology, you still need to be mindful of your references.  Numerous cases of seemingly trivial reference patterns that are actually rats nests under the hood come to mind.

From your post it doesn't sound like you're trying to implement a reset method for the purpose of object reuse (true?).  Are your objects holding any other type of resources that need to be cleaned up (i.e., streams that must be closed, any pooled or borrowed objects that must be returned)?  If the only thing you're worried about is memory dealloc then I would reconsider my object structure and attempt to verify that my objects are self contained structures that will be cleaned up at GC time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a Java Applet, you can override the Applet "destroy()" method. It is...

> ```
>  * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform
>  * this applet that it is being reclaimed and that it should destroy
>  * any resources that it has allocated. The stop() method
>  * will always be called before destroy().
> ```

Obviously not what *you* want, but might be what other people are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No Java doesn't have any destructors .The main reason behind it in Java is the Garbage Collectors that passively works in the background always and all the objects are made in the heap memory , that is the place where GC works .In c++ there we have to explicitly call the delete function since there is no Garbage collector like thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the garbage collector automatically deletes the unused objects to free up the memory. So it’s sensible Java has no destructors available.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the onDestroy() method when it comes to android programming. This is the last method that executed just before the Activity/Service class is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Missing form all the answers I just scanned is the safer replacement for finalizers.  All of the other answers are correct about using try-with-resources and avoiding finalizers as they are unreliable and are now deprecated...

However they haven't mentioned Cleaners.  Cleaners were added in Java 9 to explicitly handle the job of cleanup in a better way than finalizers.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html

Answer (score 0):

No, Java does not have a destructor in the traditional sense.

Why?

Because of

1. Automatic Garbage Collection
2. Simplicity and Reliability
3. Focus on Object-Oriented Design

Answer (score -3):

I used to mainly deal with C++ and that is what lead me to the search of a destructor as well. I am using JAVA a lot now. What I did, and it may not be the best case for everyone, but I implemented my own destructor by reseting all the values to either 0 or there default through a function.

Example:

```
public myDestructor() {

variableA = 0; //INT
variableB = 0.0; //DOUBLE & FLOAT
variableC = "NO NAME ENTERED"; //TEXT & STRING
variableD = false; //BOOL

}
```

Ideally this won't work for all situations, but where there are global variables it will work as long as you don't have a ton of them.

I know I am not the best Java programmer, but it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Try to use immutable objects more, after you 'get it' it will all make more sense :)

Comment: This isn't so much wrong as it is pointless - ie achieves nothing. If your program requires raw types to be reset in order to work correctly, then your classes instances are incorrectly scoped, meaning you are probably reassigning an existing object's properties to the properties of a new object, without creating a new Object().

Comment: Except that there are plenty of needs for resetting variables. I chose the name destructor because it fits what I am doing. It does achieve something, just nothing you understand