# The assignment operator in Java

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, memory-management

```
class App{   
    int[] a;

    private void firstFunction(){
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        a = new int[4];
        a = b;
    }

    private void secondFunction(){
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; a++) System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Both `a` and `b` are pointers toward the same memory. When `b` is out of scope, the allocated memory should be released and `a` should become null, right? Or it is based on reference-counting approach, with `b` being deleted but memory still exists?

Comment: +1, don't know why someone down voted this question. Seems good to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither. Java's garbage collection is based on *reachability* -- whether an object can be reached by some chain of references from some set of known starting points. More info [from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Thus, when `b` goes out of scope, as the array is still reachable through `a`, the array is not deallocated.

Reference counting isn't used in Java, although at least in this case I *think* it will have the same effect as Java's GC. Jon Skeet touches on the subject in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477399/does-java-support-raii-deterministic-destruction/477406#477406) answer, and says that it isn't used because it detrimentally affects performance and fails for cycles in the object graph. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/02/11/371015.aspx) post by Brad Abrams expands on that.

Answer (score 5):

Garbage collection, by definition, only deallocates memory no longer being referenced. In this case, apparently, **a** is still referencing the array.