# In Java when is the final block in a constructor executed?

Tags: java, constructor, try-finally

For example:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public Test(InputStream in){
   try{
      this.inputStream = in;
   } finally{
      inputStream.close();
   }
}
```

Is the InputStream that is passed to the instructor immediately closed after the Test object is created? Or is it closed when the Test object is destroyed? I don't know how to implement something similar to a destructor in C++.

Comment: Related: [Is there a destructor for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java)

Comment: The existing answers are sufficient, but also consider making your class implement `Closeable`, and calling `close()` on the underlying inputStream there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html

Comment: @CoryKendall thanks I think I'd better implement Closeable for my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's executed as part of a constructor. The code executed within a constructor is just normal code - there's no odd control flow there. (I mean after the call to the superclass constructor, and the variable/instance initializers being run.)

There's no equivalent to a C++ destructor in Java. The closest you'll get is a [finalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29), but that should *not* be used as the equivalent of a C++ destructor. (You should hardly ever write finalizers. There are cases where they're not called on shutdown, and they're called non-deterministically.)

In the case you've given, you would *probably* not want your class to assume responsibility for closing the input stream - usually the code which opens the stream is responsible for closing it as well. However, if you *did* want to take responsibility for that, or just make it easier for callers, you would probably want to expose a `close()` method which just closes the stream. You might want to implement [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) too, so that callers can use a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) with your class:

```
try (Test test = new Test(new FileInputStream("foo.txt")) {
    // Do stuff with test
}
```

That will call `test.close()` automatically at the end of the `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

Finally will be immediately executed after try. It does not matter it is in constructor. It is well defined in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

It says:

> A try statement with a finally block is executed by first executing the try block. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally
>     block is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement
>       completes normally.
>   - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try
>       statement completes abruptly for reason S.