# How to define destructors?

Tags: java, oop, destructor

```
    public class A {

    double wage;

    A(double wage){
    this.wage=wage;
    }

    }
```

//In this code I am supposed to define the constructors as well as destructors.

- What is the code for defining a destructor?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I am using java

Comment: there are not destructors in java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a destructor for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171952/is-there-a-destructor-for-java)

Comment: @ema - Given that there are no destructors in Java, I'm assuming you mean overriding the `finalize` method?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I basically want a method to destroy objects if there is no destuctor in java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, there are `no destructors` but you can use method [Object#finalize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) as a work around.

> The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will
>   invoke the finalize method for any given object. It is guaranteed,
>   however, that the thread that invokes finalize will not be holding any
>   user-visible synchronization locks when finalize is invoked. If an
>   uncaught exception is thrown by the finalize method, the exception is
>   ignored and finalization of that object terminates.

```
class Book {
  @Override
  public void finalize() {
    System.out.println("Book instance is getting destroyed");
  }
}

class Demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Book();//note, its not referred by variable
    System.gc();//gc, won't run for such tiny object so forced clean-up
  }
}
```

*output:*

```
Book instance is getting destroyed
```

> [System.gc()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc())
>
> Runs the garbage collector. Calling the gc method suggests that the
>   Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in
>   order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick
>   reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual
>   Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded
>   objects.
>
> The call System.gc() is effectively equivalent to the call:
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().gc()
>
> [Object#finalize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize())
>
> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection
>   determines that there are no more references to the object. A subclass
>   overrides the finalize method to dispose of system resources or to
>   perform other cleanup.

Comment: Kindly show me the code about how to use this method

Comment: What do I do in its body

Comment: What does System.gc() do? And I dont see finalize() method being used here

Comment: @ema System.gc() calls the garbage collector in java

Comment: @AnkurAnand It only *asks* the gc to be run, not actually runs it.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own method and use it. It is not recommended to override finalize method.

Comment: In my own method,if I pass the object only its reference will be destroyed not the object

Comment: if you have resorces like sockets that need to be closed, you should define your close method and close the sockets etc. and than call this method before releasing the pointer to the object.