# How to Cache InputStream for Multiple Use

Tags: java, caching, inputstream, apache-poi

I have an InputStream of a file and i use apache poi components to read from it like this:

```
POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
```

The problem is that i need to use the same stream multiple times and the POIFSFileSystem closes the stream after use.

What is the best way to cache the data from the input stream and then serve more input streams to different POIFSFileSystem ?

EDIT 1:

By cache i meant store for later use, not as a way to speedup the application. Also is it better to just read up the input stream into an array or string and then create input streams for each use ?

EDIT 2:

Sorry to reopen the question, but the conditions are somewhat different when working inside desktop and web application. 
First of all, the InputStream i get from the org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem in my tomcat web app doesn't support markings thus cannot reset.

Second, I'd like to be able to keep the file in memory for faster acces and less io problems when dealing with files.

Comment: see my "Edit 2" in my post; I'm hoping that it works

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can decorate InputStream being passed to *POIFSFileSystem* with a version that when close() is called it respond with reset():

```
class ResetOnCloseInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream decorated;

    public ResetOnCloseInputStream(InputStream anInputStream) {
        if (!anInputStream.markSupported()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("marking not supported");
        }

        anInputStream.mark( 1 << 24); // magic constant: BEWARE
        decorated = anInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        decorated.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return decorated.read();
    }
}
```

### testcase

```
static void closeAfterInputStreamIsConsumed(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
    int r;

    while ((r = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(r);
    }

    is.close();
    System.out.println("=========");

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("sample".getBytes());
    ResetOnCloseInputStream decoratedIs = new ResetOnCloseInputStream(is);
    closeAfterInputStreamIsConsumed(decoratedIs);
    closeAfterInputStreamIsConsumed(decoratedIs);
    closeAfterInputStreamIsConsumed(is);
}
```

### EDIT 2

you can read the entire file in a byte[] (slurp mode) then passing it to a ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: How big files does it handle while using the magic constant in
anInputStream.mark( 1 << 24) ?

Comment: forget about it, you can make it a parameter

Comment: I just put Integer.MAX_VALUE , anyway thanks it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Michael-O `mark` sets the home for the stream to return to when `reset` is called https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark(int)

Comment: this (.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) will only work for files <2 GB

Comment: @rwijngaa For such case maybe `InputStream` is not the best option. I'd rather explore `FileChannel` instead.

Answer (score 23):

Try BufferedInputStream, which adds mark and reset functionality to another input stream, and just override its close method:

```
public class UnclosableBufferedInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {

    public UnclosableBufferedInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
        super.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
    }
}
```

So:

```
UnclosableBufferedInputStream  bis = new UnclosableBufferedInputStream (inputStream);
```

and use `bis` wherever inputStream was used before.

Comment: Please check EDIT2 of the question:
"... the InputStream i get ... doesn't support markings thus cannot reset..."

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your InputStream supports it or not. BufferedInputStream wraps around another stream, buffers the input, and supports marking on its own. 

The overridden close method, will also conveniently reset it, whenever it's consumed.

Comment: why would you like to reset it when you ask from it to be closed? is it really needed? shouldn't we just call reset() when we wish to ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper If you are using a library, for example, that needs an `InputStream` and closes it after using it.

Comment: @Timmos i am not sure you've understood me. i can see in the "close()" method that he called "reset()" . i don't understand why he did it. isn't it really a bad thing to keep inputStreams alive all the time?

Comment: @androiddeveloper In general, yes. For file input streams, for example. What I do is a combination of the 2 proposed solution in the accepted answer. I read the file into a `byte[]` and then pass this into a `ByteArrayInputStream`, which I keep open by calling `reset()` in the `close()` method. But this last step is unnecessary as the Javadoc for `ByteArrayInputStream` states: "Closing a ByteArrayInputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException."

Comment: @Timmos cool. thanks. i wonder though how i can use an inputStream of the internet and be able to go back in it, maybe using a custom input stream. for some reason , using BufferedInputStream didn't always work for me. i've posted a question about it, but didn't find a good solution. here's the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774442/how-to-get-bitmap-information-and-then-decode-bitmap-from-internet-inputstream . it seems like it works on most websites, but not on others. weird.

Comment: @androiddeveloper @timmos as I remember, I didn't want some library to close my `InputStream` because I still needed it, so I ended up having an overloaded close method with a parameter `public void close(bool reallyClose)` to close it when I'm done with it, not when the library is

Comment: Not closing the source input stream is bad, please don't do that. If Input Stream are left open it does not free up the underlying OS resources, the file handles, e.g. files cannot be renamed or moved, sockets are not freed, and the program may even reach the file handle limit set by the OS. I'm [proposing a variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47575785/48136) that will close the decorated input stream while keeping the actual data cached.

Answer (score 6):

This works correctly:

```
byte[] bytes = getBytes(inputStream);
POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

where getBytes is like this:

```
private static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
int n;
baos.reset();

while ((n = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
      baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }

   return baos.toByteArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below implementation for more custom use -

```
public class ReusableBufferedInputStream extends BufferedInputStream
{

    private int totalUse;
    private int used;

    public ReusableBufferedInputStream(InputStream in, Integer totalUse)
    {
        super(in);
        if (totalUse > 1)
        {
            super.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            this.totalUse = totalUse;
            this.used = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.totalUse = 1;
            this.used = 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        if (used < totalUse)
        {
            super.reset();
            ++used;
        }
        else
        {
            super.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not that big, read it into a `byte[]` array and give POI a `ByteArrayInputStream` created from that array.

If the file is big, then you shouldn't care, since the OS will do the caching for you as best as it can.

[EDIT] Use [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to read the File into a byte array in an efficient way. Do not use `int read()` since it reads the file byte by byte which is *very* slow!

If you want to do it yourself, use a `File` object to get the length, create the array and the a loop which reads bytes from the file. You must loop since `read(byte[], int offset, int len)` can read less than `len` bytes (and usually does).

Comment: the Read() method returns int, how do i split the bytes: little or big endian ?

Comment: read returns always 0-255 or -1. Check first for -1(end of stream) and then you can cast it safety to byte.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean with "cache"? Do you want the different POIFSFileSystem to start at the beginning of the stream? If so, there's absolutely no point caching anything in your Java code; it will be done by the OS, just open a new stream.

Or do you wan to continue reading at the point where the first POIFSFileSystem stopped? That's not caching, and it's very difficult to do. The only way I can think of if you can't avoid the stream getting closed would be to write a thin wrapper that counts how many bytes have been read and then open a new stream and skip that many bytes. But that could fail when POIFSFileSystem internally uses something like a BufferedInputStream.

Comment: Not very wise to presume that the input stream is resetable indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would implemented, to be safely used with any InputStream :

- write your own InputStream wrapper where you create a temporary file to mirror the original stream content
- dump everything read from the original input stream into this temporary file
- when the stream was completely read you will have all the data mirrored in the temporary file
- use InputStream.reset to switch(initialize) the internal stream to a FileInputStream(mirrored_content_file)
- from now on you will loose the reference of the original stream(can be collected)
- add a new method release() which will remove the temporary file and release any open stream.
- you can even call release() from *finalize* to be sure the temporary file is release in case you forget to call release()(most of the time you should avoid using *finalize*, always call a method to release object resources). see [Why would you ever implement finalize()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158174/why-would-you-ever-implement-finalize)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(IOUtils.toInputStream("Foobar"));
    inputStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(inputStream));
    inputStream.reset();
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(inputStream));
}
```

This works.  IOUtils is part of commons IO.

Answer (score 1):

This answer iterates on previous ones <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303314/48136)|[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959357/48136)</sup> based on the `BufferInputStream`. The main changes are that it allows infinite reuse. And takes care of closing the original source input stream to free-up system resources. Your OS defines a limit on those and you don't want the program to run out of file handles (*That's also why you should always 'consume' responses e.g. with the apache `EntityUtils.consumeQuietly()`*). **EDIT** Updated the code to handle for gready consumers that use `read(buffer, offset, length)`, in that case it may happen that `BufferedInputStream` tries hard to look at the source, this code protects against that use.

```
public class CachingInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {    
    public CachingInputStream(InputStream source) {
        super(new PostCloseProtection(source));
        super.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        if (!((PostCloseProtection) in).decoratedClosed) {
            in.close();
        }
        super.reset();
    }

    private static class PostCloseProtection extends InputStream {
        private volatile boolean decoratedClosed = false;
        private final InputStream source;

        public PostCloseProtection(InputStream source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read();
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read(b);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? -1 : source.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            return decoratedClosed ? 0 : source.skip(n);
        }

        @Override
        public int available() throws IOException {
            return source.available();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            decoratedClosed = true;
            source.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void mark(int readLimit) {
            source.mark(readLimit);
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() throws IOException {
            source.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean markSupported() {
            return source.markSupported();
        }
    }
}
```

To reuse it just close it first if it wasn't.

One limitation though is that if the stream is closed before the whole content of the original stream has been read, then this decorator will have incomplete data, so make sure the whole stream is read before closing.

Answer (score 0):

I just add my solution here, as this works for me. It basically is a combination of the top two answers :)

```
    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    Writer w = new StringWriter();
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    Reader r;
    is.mark(1 << 24);
    try {
        r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n=r.read(buf)) != -1) {
            w.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        is.reset();
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.debug(this.getClass(), "Cannot convert stream to string.", e);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Logger.debug(this.getClass(), "Cannot convert stream to string.", e);
    }
    return w.toString();
}
```

Comment: It is great that it works for you, but you shoudln't put answers to your problems, but answers to the questions asked ;)

Comment: This is my solution on how to cache an InputStream for multiple use. Isn't that the problem you submitted?

Comment: I appreciate your effort. And for the problem I submitted, sometimes details make it different. The question I asked is a bit more specific, a multiple use of a _Stream_ to be consumed by _Apache POI_ which may or may not work with _String_. So you actually answered more general question, and not the more specific I posted. That's why the most specific answer won.