# SocketInputStream and InputStream Supporting Reset() or MarkSupported()

Tags: java, inputstream

I am trying to create a sample which is getting `InputStream` in the form of `SocketInputStream`. It is not supported `reset()` and `mark()`. Now once I process this input stream  I can process it again for other operation because it get closed, reached at eof.
Like I want to use this process for `InputStream` which is allowing `reset()` and `markSupported()`.

How can I deal with `InputStream` in such situation.

Comment: Making sure I follow: You want a way to process all `InputStream` instances such that `reset` and `mark` are supported (e.g., using a wrapper `InputStream`)?

Comment: Is your problem similar to the one found here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732961/getting-an-inputstream-to-read-more-than-once-regardless-of-marksupported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, by default `SocketInputStream` does not support `mark()` and `reset()`.   A network stream is not something that you can reposition.  There is nothing that is storing the bytes that have been already read so the stream can never go back.

That said, you could extend `SocketInputStream` and provide that functionality.  You would need to override the `SocketInputStream.read(byte b[], int off, int length)` method and store information in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or some other running `byte[]`.  Whenever the mark is repositioned, you would need to read from the `byte[]` only issuing a `super.read(...)` if you are at the end of your internal array.

It's a good bit of work to get right however and you are going to have to be *very* careful about memory here.

Comment: Thanks I have this idea but I wanted to do it without OutputStream. – 

But thanks for your suggestion. I will try it.