# Java I/O - Reuse InputStream Object

Tags: java, inputstream

Is there anyway to reuse an inputStream by changing its content? (Without new statement).
For instance, I was able to something very close to my requirement, but not enough
In the following code I am using a `SequenceInputStream`, and everytime I am adding a new `InputStream` to that sequence.
But I would like to do the same thing by using the same inputStream (I don't care which implementation of `InputStream`).
I thought about `mark()`/`reset()` APIs, but i still need to change the content to be read.

The idea to avoid new `InputStream` creations is because of performance issues

```
     //Input Streams
    List<InputStream> inputStreams = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    try{
        //First InputStream
        byte[] input = new byte[]{24,8,102,97};
        inputStreams.add(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));

        Enumeration<InputStream> enu = Collections.enumeration(inputStreams);
        SequenceInputStream is = new SequenceInputStream(enu);

        byte [] out = new byte[input.length];
        is.read(out);

        for (byte b : out){
            System.out.println(b);//Will print 24,8,102,97
        }

        //Second InputStream
        input = new byte[]{ 4,66};
        inputStreams.add(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
        out = new byte[input.length];
        is.read(out);

        for (byte b : out){
            System.out.println(b);//will print 4,66
        }
        is.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//
    }
```

Comment: `Vector`! We are in the 21th century!

Comment: consider `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`, you will win on the performance

Comment: @AndrewTobilko are you sure about that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Escape_analysis_and_lock_coarsening specifically cites an example of `Vector` not locking unless necessary in Java 6+. Of course, that relies upon the escape analysis detecting that locking is unnecessary; using `ArrayList` means that no locking is done ever (unless done explicitly), so you have more control over the performance.

Comment: I changed to List so everybody is happier...but that's not the point of my question. This is only a sample code in order to explain my point...

Comment: @DisplayName `Vector` is so 20th Century. ;)

Answer (score 7):

No, You can't restart reading the input stream after it reaches to the end of the stream as it is uni-directional i.e. moves only in single direction.

But Refer below links, they may help:

[How to Cache InputStream for Multiple Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924990/how-to-cache-inputstream-for-multiple-use)

[Getting an InputStream to read more than once, regardless of markSupported()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732961/getting-an-inputstream-to-read-more-than-once-regardless-of-marksupported)

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own implementation (subclass) of `InputStream` that would allow what you require. I doubt there is an existing implementation of this.

I highly doubt you'll get any measurable performance boost from this though, there's not much of logic in e.g. `FileInputStream` that you wouldn't need to perform anyways, and Java is well optimized for garbage-collecting short-lived objects.