# How to use all files in a Java program in RAM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Is there a way to have all files used in a Java application in RAM? I don't need to have file synchronization, just need to put the file in RAM when opened for the first time and every writes will write in RAM and every reads will read from the RAM. Basically, I need to redefine standard file behaviour in Java. Any help?

This is for unit test only, my tests need a lot of file operations (~15% of the time) and I want to try something new. In a perfect world this should be done without changing my original code (an AspectJ aspect or a JVM argument will be awesome)

Comment: You would need to use some kind of cache instead of the IO or NIO API.

Comment: You could create your own InputStream or use a RAM disk

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924990/how-to-cache-inputstream-for-multiple-use

Answer (score 0):

You can use file streams to load all the bytes of the file in RAM.
Just use a `byte[]` to load all the file and then close it and access the array.