# Reading Ring request body when already read

Tags: clojure, ring

My question is, how can I idiomatically read the body of a Ring request if it has already been read?

Here's the background.  I'm writing an error handler for a Ring app.  When an error occurs, I want to log the error, including all relevant information that I might need to reproduce and fix the error.  One important piece of information is the body of the request.  However, the statefulness of the `:body` value (because it is a type of `java.io.InputStream` object) causes problems.

Specifically, what happens is that some middleware (the `ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-body` middleware in my case) does a `slurp` on the body `InputStream` object, which changes the internal state of the object such that future calls to `slurp` return an empty string.  Thus, the [content of the] body is effectively lost from the request map.

The only solution I can think of is to preemptively copy the body `InputStream` object before the body can be read, just in case I might need it later.  I don't like this approach because it seems clumsy to do some work on every request just in case there might be an error later.  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a lib that sucks up the body, replaces it with a stream with identical contents, and stores the original so that it can be deflated later.

[groundhog](https://github.com/noisesmith/groundhog)

This is not adequate for indefinitely open streams, and is a bad idea if the body is the upload of some large object. But it helps for testing, and recreating error conditions as a part of the debugging process.

If all you need is a duplicate of the stream, you can use the [tee-stream](https://github.com/noisesmith/groundhog/blob/master/src/noisesmith/groundhog.clj#L67) function from groundhog as the basis for your own middleware.

Comment: The approach I took is based on `tee-stream`. Thanks for that, and for `groundhog`. I'm accepting this answer, and I'll detail my approach in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I adopted @noisesmith's basic approach with a few modifications, as shown below.  Each of these functions can be used as Ring middleware.

```
(defn with-request-copy
  "Transparently store a copy of the request in the given atom.
  Blocks until the entire body is read from the request.  The request
  stored in the atom (which is also the request passed to the handler)
  will have a body that is a fresh (and resettable) ByteArrayInputStream
  object."
  [handler atom]
  (fn [{orig-body :body :as request}]
    (let [{body :stream} (groundhog/tee-stream orig-body)
          request-copy (assoc request :body body)]
      (reset! atom request-copy)
      (handler request-copy))))

(defn wrap-error-page
  "In the event of an exception, do something with the exception
  (e.g. report it using an exception handling service) before
  returning a blank 500 response.  The `handle-exception` function
  takes two arguments: the exception and the request (which has a
  ready-to-slurp body)."
  [handler handle-exception]
  ;; Note that, as a result of this top-level approach to
  ;; error-handling, the request map sent to Rollbar will lack any
  ;; information added to it by one of the middleware layers.
  (let [request-copy (atom nil)
        handler (with-request-copy handler request-copy)]
    (fn [request]
      (try
        (handler request)
        (catch Throwable e
          (.reset (:body @request-copy))
          ;; You may also want to wrap this line in a try/catch block.
          (handle-exception e @request-copy)
          {:status 500})))))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb but I don't get quite how this is working. The whole point of tee-stream is that it returns both the contents of the stream plus a new stream, but you're ignoring the returned contents so what is it achieving?

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe the important bit is that the `:stream` is an instance of `ByteArrayInputStream`, which can be `.reset`, as `wrap-error-page` does.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're stuck with some sort of "keep a copy around just in case" strategy.  Unfortunately it looks like `:body` on the request [must be an `InputStream`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/SPEC#L88) and nothing else (on the response it can be a `String` or other things which is why I mention it)

Sketch: In a very early middleware, wrap the `:body` InputStream in an `InputStream` that resets itself on close ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925036/69689)).  Not all `InputStream`s can be reset, so you may need to do some copying here.  Once wrapped, the stream can be re-read on close, and you're good.  There's memory risk here if you have giant requests.

Update: here's an half-baked attempt, inspired in part by `tee-stream` in groundhog.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :refer [copy]])
(defn wrap-resettable-body
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let [orig-body (:body request)
          baos (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.)
          _ (copy orig-body baos)
          ba (.toByteArray baos)
          bais (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream. ba)
          ;; bais doesn't need to be closed, and supports resetting, so wrap it
          ;; in a delegating proxy that calls its reset when closed.
          resettable (proxy [java.io.InputStream] []
                       (available [] (.available bais))
                       (close [] (.reset bais))
                       (mark [read-limit] (.mark bais read-limit))
                       (markSupported [] (.markSupported bais))
                       ;; exercise to reader: proxy with overloaded methods...
                       ;; (read [] (.read bais))
                       (read [b off len] (.read bais b off len))
                       (reset [] (.reset bais))
                       (skip [n] (.skip bais)))
          updated-req (assoc request :body resettable)]
      (handler updated-req))))
```

Comment: Good idea; that approach would allow transparent re-`slurp`ing.  Unfortunately for me, the actual `InputStream` object is more specifically a `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput` object, which is not `reset`table.  But I think your approach is sound.  I'll accept this answer if you sketch a solution that works in the un-reset-able case, or if nobody else does the same within a couple of days.

Comment: @JeffTerrell I think you could wrap the HttpInput in a BufferedInputStream and further wrap that in the resettable one.  I'm curious and am going to try it.

Comment: clojure.java.io/input-stream should return a BufferedInputStream for you.

Comment: I like the suggestion of replacing the input stream with a resettable one. I may borrow that idea for my groundhog project (currently I store / deflate but automatic reset seems like a nice behavior).

Comment: @noisesmith One downside of this approach that I'm thinking about: who actually closes the original stream?  It is wrapped in the ResettableStream whose close() is overridden.  I think I prefer your tee-stream approach!

Comment: I think your approach would work. Thanks for detailing it. Sorry to go back on what I said, but I'm accepting the other answer because it's simpler and cleaner.