# how to read an input stream without closing it in Java?

Tags: java, inputstream

I want to read an input stream twice but after the first usage, the stream gets closed and I am not able to use it again. CloseShieldInputStream also doesn't seem to help. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Which language are you working in? What have you tried till now? Show us the code.

Comment: It's java. basically I am detecting the mime type and length of the input stream and then I am supposed to pass it to the output stream. The signature of the method is something like this : public void execute(InputStream input, OutputStream output)

Comment: After detecting the MIME type and length, do you want to process the _remainder_ of the stream? Or do you want to start reading it from the very beginning again?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924990/how-to-cache-inputstream-for-multiple-use

Answer (score 0):

Save input stream into `byte[]` and then read it as many as you want.