# Wait for Garbage Collection of a specific object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was just digging around in the commons-io library and found this:

```
Keeps track of files awaiting deletion, and deletes them when
an associated marker object is reclaimed by the garbage collector.
```

This can be found in the documentation for the [`FileCleaningTracker`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileCleaningTracker.html) object.

Now I am just curious how I can do this by myself? How can my code detect when an object is reclaimed by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Library/apache-common-IO/org/apache/commons/io/FileCleaningTracker.java.htm), it uses the [PhantomReference](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) class. According to the documentation:

> Phantom reference objects, which are enqueued after the collector determines that their referents may otherwise be reclaimed. **Phantom references are most often used for scheduling pre-mortem cleanup actions in a more flexible way than is possible with the Java finalization mechanism.**
>
> If the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that the referent of a phantom reference is phantom reachable, then at that time or at some later time it will enqueue the reference.
>
> In order to ensure that a reclaimable object remains so, the referent of a phantom reference may not be retrieved: The get method of a phantom reference always returns null.
>
> Unlike soft and weak references, phantom references are not automatically cleared by the garbage collector as they are enqueued. An object that is reachable via phantom references will remain so until all such references are cleared or themselves become unreachable.

The `PhantomReference` constructor accepts two arguments:

> `referent` - the object the new phantom reference will refer to
>
> `q` - the queue with which the reference is to be registered, or null if registration is not required

The `q` argument is an instance of the `ReferenceQueue` class. The `PhantomReference` will be added to this `ReferenceQueue` when it's `referent` becomes phantom reachable. When this happens, you can retrieve the `PhantomReference` by using the `poll()` or `remove()` methods of the `ReferenceQueue` class.

For example:

```
T objectToWatch = ...;
ReferenceQueue<T> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<T>();
new PhantomReference<T>(objectToWatch, referenceQueue);

// Later on, probably in another thread...
Reference<? extends T> nextReference = referenceQueue.remove();
// Tidy up!
```

Note: `PhantomReference` has sibling classes named [`SoftReference`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) and [`WeakReference`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) that may also be of use. The relationship between these are documented in the [java.lang.ref package documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this really answers your question, but the finalize() method of an object is called prior to its resources being reclaimed.

Edit: Which means that you can send a message to another object to alert it, or something along those lines.

Comment: Do not use finalizers for this purpose, or any other if you can avoid it. There is no guarantee that the finalize() method will be called promptly following garbage collection, or even that it will be called at all (See Effective Java 2nd Ed, Item 7). 

The java.lang.ref package is the way to go.

Comment: If you can help it, don't use finalizers! http://stackoverflow.com/a/158791/74694