# Input Stream Issue

Tags: java, android, inputstream, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

stuck in One Issue ,

I am using `BluetoothSocket` class, I am sending and receiving data with the help of input and output streams.

when App receives large amount of data from input stream,  I am killing my app forcefully and after it I am again restarting my app, but `InputStream` returns me previous data, which is not needed anymore.how to discard that old data?

has Anyone Some Solution for this Issue?

**Following is my source code:**

```
public class MyBluetoothService {
private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

// Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
// service and the UI.
private interface MessageConstants {
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

    // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
        // member streams are final.
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
        }
        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                        mmBuffer);
                readMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);

            // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
            Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                    MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
            writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

            // Send a failure message back to the activity.
            Message writeErrorMsg =
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("toast",
                    "Couldn't send data to the other device");
            writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work fine if you normally close your app?(when cancel() is called)

Comment: ya, It is Working Fine. @KYHSGeekCode

Comment: Then how about trying implementing the finalizer to ensure the close happen?

Comment: Also it is safer to close streams too before closing the socket :)

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/158216/8614565 .

Comment: Usual problem. You are totally ignoring the value returned by `read()`. This means (i) you are ignoring end of stream on the socket, when `read()` returns -1, and (II) you are also ignoring the return value when it is positive, which is the number of bytes received. Don't write code like this.

Comment: @EJP i have assigned `read()` value to `numbyte`.

Comment: And then you have totally ignored it from there on, specifically including the end of stream issue. Do I really have to explain your own code to you?

Comment: Edited my answer I hope it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
```

The problem is here. You should keep reading from the stream until *end of stream or* an exception occurs. You need to break out of the read loop if `read()` returns -1.

At present you are reading beyond end of stream, and ignoring the condition altogether, so of course the data that was in the buffer on the last successful read is still there.

For your application to keep *seeing* that data, you must also be ignoring the read count and assuming the buffer was filled, which also is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should close the socket to manage the bug.

I recommend you to do this in finalizer like the code below.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread
 {
 private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
 private final InputStream mmInStream;
 private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
 private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream
 @override
 protected void finalize() throws Throwable
 {
   try
   {
       cancel();
   }
   finally
   {
        super.finalize();
   }
 }
...
```

Also as I mentioned in comment, it is safer to close every `stream`s before closing the socket.

So, try this `cancel()` method.

```
// Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
 public void cancel()
 {
     try {
        mmInStream.close();
     } catch( NullPointerException | IOException e) {}
    try {
        mmOutStream.close();
     } catch( NullPointerException | IOException e) {}

     try
     {
         mmSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
     }
 }
```

And [more information](https://dzone.com/articles/java-what-does-finalize-do-and) about `finalize` method.

**EDIT: bold ones are important than other suggestions.**

Reading comments of EJP I understood why your app stops when you get large data : you maybe have to clear buffers before calling `read()`. And he says that finalizer can happen not to be called by system (I don't know why).
**How about** `break`**ing the loop when the** `read()` **returned** `-1`?

And just now I found a helpful [link](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=283) about proper method to read a stream. I hope it helped.

Code cited from the link

> ```
> private String extract(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
>  {
>           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>                       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
>       int read = 0;
>       while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
>           baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
>       }   
>           baos.flush();
>         return new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
>   }
> ```

*Also*
Though the `finalizer` may be able not to be called by system closing `streams` before closing `sockets` is safer (I read some SO threads before).

Comment: still the previous data is there in input stream.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a finaliser method will ever run, and no stated reason as to how this will solve the actual problem.

Comment: @EJP how can't the finalizer method be called?

Comment: There is no guarantee that *garbage-collection* ever runs, let alone finalisers. I can only suggest that you read the Javadoc. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP even when the app is forcefully killed as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode Even whenever. There is no guarantee.

Comment: @EJP Aha I got some. Then what should I do to make a code executed always?

Comment: NB Your mostly irrelevant link is wrong to say that a `ByteArrayOutputStream` needs flushing. It doesn't, and the Javadoc explicitly says so. Not that it has anything to with the question.

Comment: @EJP Then I think read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)  this line is more important isn't it? Then is != -1 or read(buffer,0,length)(instrad of read(buffer)) is more important?

Comment: The -1 test and using the read count are what's important. `read(buffer)` and `read(buffer,0,buffer.length)` are equivalent, as it states clearly in the Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @EJP and  KYHSGeekCode for your help. It works for me.